# Swift EXC_BREAKPOINT when assigning viewcontroller to variable in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift

Im getting an error when trying to perform a variable assignment with my destinationViewController.

The error message is this:
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

This in my prepareForSegue function.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "LoginSegue"{

        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as LoggedInViewController
        vc.email = emailTextfield.text

    }
}
```

In the other file it looks like this.

```
var email: String?
```

which is at the top. 
Then this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("Email is:")
    println(email)
    println("Email was")
}
```

But i never come into the second file.

It is the line let vc = segue.destinationViewController as LoggedInViewController that is marked with error.

Both swift files are connected to navigation controllers.

I dont know what more you need, but I will of course post all code you need to understand!

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your case destination controller is navigation controller not your **LoggedInViewController** , So `segue.destinationViewController as LoggedInViewController` is an error , therefore it is crashing.

Try like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "LoginSegue"{
            let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController

        let vc = navigationController.topViewController as LoggedInViewController
        vc.email = emailTextfield.text

    }
}
```

Comment: Damn that works! :D Can't upvote tho, only got 1 rep! :( But thanks for taking some time to help me :)

Comment: Yeah, noticed! I have now!

Comment: I just got a similiar error, I actually use the same but instead of `navigationController.viewControllers[0]` I use `navigationController.topViewController`. Is there a difference?

Comment: @OliverBorchert You are right. you should use topViewController to get the current view controller on the navigation stack. viewControllers[0] gives the bottom view controller. I just edited my answer , Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody comes here because it's the first hit on EXC_BREAKPOINT:

For me this very telling exception was thrown because of a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` that happened because an IBOutlet was used before it was initialized.