# Set label to title of navigation item - Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, segue

I have two table views (`DayTVC & AddDayTVC`). The title of the navigation item in the `DayTVC` represents the selected week. Is there a way to transfer the title of the navigation item (`DayTVC`) to a label on the `AddDayTVC`? I tried this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == "addDay" {            
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as AddDayTableViewController
        let sender = sender as DayTableViewController
        destinationController.nameLabel.text = sender.navigationItem.title
    }
}
```

But every time I trie to get to `AddDayTVC` I get the following error

```
Thread 1: EXC_Breakpoint (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)"
```

for this line

```
let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as AddDayTableViewController
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error indicates that the cast operation (`as AddDayTableViewController`) is failing because `segue.destinationViewController` isn't a `AddDayTableViewController`.

Comment: Check your storyboard and make sure you have the ViewController class set correctly.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider a conditional cast, so you can do something more informative than crashing.  My template is: `if segue.identifier == "XXXX" { if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? YYYY { ... } }`

Comment: I checked the classes of all view controllers as well as the identifier of the segue between DayTVC and AddDayTVC - everything was correct. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How are you performing the segue?  The other possibility is that it's the `sender as` cast that's failing.  Or that `destinationController.nameLabel` is nil.

Comment: I'm using a bar button item to perform the segue (modal).  If I alt + click nameLabel or any other variable Xcode's gives me the right documentation.

Comment: @Mediano, have you seen this post yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554361/swift-exc-breakpoint-when-assigning-viewcontroller-to-variable-in-prepareforsegu?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Since you're triggering the segue with a `UIBarButtonItem`, the sender will be that button and the cast:

```
    let sender = sender as DayTableViewController
```

will fail and throw the indicated exception.  Since this code is (probably) located in the `DayTableViewController`, why not just use self instead?

Comment: I tried it like this but it won't work `navigationController.nameLabel.text = self.navigationItem.title`